# AMS Subject Classification not showing

Tags: amsart, journal-publishing, journal

I am using the latex template for the journal : Linear and Multilinear Algebra, from  Taylor and Francis.

I am using `\documentclass[]{interact}`. Further, inside the `\begin{document}` after `\begin{keywords}****\end{keywords}` I am using the command `\subjclass[2010]{**C**(primary), and **C**(secondary)}`. There is no error. But the subject code is not showing in the pdf.

So where is the mistake? Please help.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this document class? Also, instead of code snippets, please provide an abstracted, complete, minimal example that replicates your behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the class file, there is an environment called 'amscode'. I believe this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: it would be helpful to say where this class file can be found.  it's not on ctan as far as i can tell.

Comment: The class file seems to only be available from Taylor & Francis.

Comment: The 'amscode' environment has the same syntax as the 'keywords' environment in this class. In other words, you would use \begin{amscode}33C50\end{amscode}